# read operation against pipe(2) doesn't block the process

Tags: c, pipe

I'm studying C pipes and reading the documentation from the manual (man 7 pipe) I saw this line

> If  a  process  attempts  to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until
> data is available

So I decided to do a simple test and trying to understand what is going on but I found out that the process attempting to read from the pipe is not blocked and I don't understand why. Could you help me? This is the code I'm using

```
    int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
        close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */
        printf("son: %i", getpid());

        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
        close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
        //write(pipefd[1], "this is an example", strlen("this is an example"));
        printf("father: %i", getpid());
        close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
        wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have closed the father's pipe.  That causes a broken pipe in the child.  The child will not block on a broken pipe.

Comment: Hi, I understand you are referring to the line immediately below of ```printf("father: %i", getpid());``` right?

Comment: Yes - the child might take some time to start.  You may have closed the pipe before the child even started.

Comment: I tried commenting the problematic line and uncommenting  the line ```write(pipefd[1], "this is an example", strlen("this is an example"))``` and now my program doesn't stop, I think it is cycling over the ```wait(NULL)``` line and the child is in the while loop.

Is there an optimal way to ensure that when the child starts its execution doesn't find a broken pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` will block when reading from a pipe if no data is currently available *but the other end is still open*.

This should make sense: if the other end is still open, then the writer might eventually write something, and we should wait to read it.  But if the other end is closed, there is no possible way for anything further to be written.  If we blocked we would block forever, which accomplishes nothing.  So `read` returns 0 instead, analogous to end-of-file when reading from a regular file.  Again, this makes sense: we have come to the end of the data that the parent wrote, and now we need to move on with our life.

What you observe here is exactly what one would want in a normal program: the child is going to print out everything that the parent writes to the pipe, and then print a newline and exit.  In this case the parent writes nothing to the pipe, so the child writes nothing, followed by the newline and exiting.

If you'd like to see the child block, then put in a delay before the parent's `close(pipefd[1])`, e.g. `sleep(5);`.  But that is pointless except as a demonstration.

Per your comment, removing the `close(pipefd[1])` altogether is definitely wrong.  The child won't see EOF until the writing end is closed, and it won't exit until it sees EOF.  But the parent is calling `wait()`, and won't continue until the child exits, and you have a classic [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Also note that the term "broken pipe" means something else - it refers to the situation when a process attempts to *write* to a pipe for which the *reading* end has been closed.  The two cases are not handled symmetrically.  A true "broken pipe" results in the writing process receiving a SIGPIPE signal, which normally will kill it.  The idea is that under normal circumstances, we would expect the reading process to keep reading until all the data is consumed.  If it closes the reading end before that happens, it's assumed that something has gone wrong, and there is no point in having the writing process continue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thank you for your reply, it gave me a lot more perspective on the underlying problem